# Get all methods from C# source code

Tags: c#, reflection, codedom

I am looking forward to get all method names used in C# using following code:

```
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters()
{
    GenerateExecutable = false,
    GenerateInMemory = true
};

var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
foreach (string path_file in files)
{
    string source = File.ReadAllText(path_file);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(source);
    CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source);

    if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
    {
        foreach (var error in results.Errors)
            Console.Out.WriteLine(error.ToString());
        return;
    }
}
```

I am trying to read the source code in a variable source and passing this in `CompileAssemblyFromSource` method of `CSharpCodeProvider` class.

I am getting the following error under result variable.

> c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\2rdqotiv.0.cs(3,14) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?).

Can anyone please help me to solve this error? I am using MVS 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the referenced assemblies, for example:

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location);
```

You can also add assemblies manually, as follows:

```
string exDir = $@"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v{ver}";
parameters.CompilerOptions = $"/lib:{exDir}";
```

And BTW, you could also use `CompileAssemblyFromFile` instead of having to open the files manually.